# My original list is changing when using append or extend

Tags: python, list, append, extend

I would like to know if this is normal behavior for Python. Code is:

```
>>>abcd = [["a","b","c","d"],[1,2,3,4]]
>>>testlist = []
```

then

`>>>testlist.extend(abcd)`

or if I use:

```
>>>for item in abcd:
    testlist.append(item)
```

the result of calling testlist is the same, which is perfectly fine:

```
>>>testlist
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

but then when I do something with 'testlist' the change appears also in 'abcd'

```
>>>testlist[0].append("anything")
>>>testlist
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'anything'], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>>abcd
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'anything'], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

It is making me crazy. How should I proceed without changing original list and not making copies of it every time I need to pull some data from it. Thank you.

Comment: There's only one list object. You're never making a copy of your list. Putting it into another list doesn't create a copy of it.

Comment: You have to distinguish between deep and shallow copies. In your case testlist seems to be a shallow copy, as changes to one are reflected also in the other. Thus, you might want to look into deep copying list.

Comment: This link might help you more in understanding different ways for copying list in python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between deep and shallow copies. In your case testlist seems to be a shallow copy, as changes to one are reflected also in the other. Thus, you might want to look into deep copying list.

For example:

```
import copy
testlist = copy.deepcopy(abcd)
```

or even simpler:

```
testlist = abcd[:]
```

Comment: It is not a shallow copy either, you just assign a new name to the _same_ list, it's a reference. There is no copying involved. The solution by assigning to a slice is correct, but the explanation is not.

Comment: @Jan There *is* a form of shallow-copying going on with `testlist.extend(abcd)` or `for item in abcd: testlist.append(item)`…!

Comment: @Imago `testlist = abcd[:]` just makes a shallow copy and will produce the same issue…!

Comment: Yes the slice is a new object indeed, but in `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = a`, there is no copying involved when assigning to `b`.

Comment: @Jan True. But I'm not sure how this relates to anything, as I don't see `b = a` happening anywhere.

Comment: Extending a list with another list is basically the same operation, but yeah, sorry for going on a tangent here.

Comment: @Jan Not really at all. Extending takes *the elements* from one list and appends them to the other. The list itself is not taken.

Comment: Ack, sure, sorry, I am confused. Thanks.